# Customizing pagerTemplate with lazy load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a gallery and I'm using this gallery with [lazySizes](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes) and I'm trying to get all images to with lazy.

However, the images of my pager thumbnails are not working. The images must be loaded from the `data-exthumbimage` attribute on the `a` tags.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function generateSlider() {
    $(".mySlideShow").cycle({
      next: "#single-right",
      log: false,
      fx: "fade",
      caption: ".cycle-caption",
      captionTemplate: "{{title}}",
      pauseOnHover: true,
      pager: "#single-pager",
      pagerTemplate: "<a href='#'><img class='lazyload' data-src='{{parents.0.exthumbimage}}' width=60 height=60></a>",
      prev: "#single-left",
      slides: "a[data-hidden='false']"
    });
  }

  generateSlider();

  $(".filter li").on("click", function() {
    var activeId = $(this).attr("id");
    if (activeId == "show-all") {
      $("a").attr("data-hidden", "false");
    } else {
      $("a").attr("data-hidden", "true");
      $("a[data-id = '" + activeId + "']").attr("data-hidden", "false");
    }
    $(".mySlideShow").cycle("destroy");
    generateSlider();
  });

  $(" .mySlideShow").lightGallery({
    exThumbImage: "data-exthumbimage",
    download: false,
    thumbnail: true,
    loadYoutubeThumbnail: true,
    youtubeThumbSize: "default",
    loadVimeoThumbnail: true,
    vimeoThumbSize: "thumbnail_medium"
  });
});
```

```css
.single-gallery {
  width: 800px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.cycle-slideshow img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 494px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

#single-pager a img {
  width: 49.3px !important;
  height: 49.3px !important;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

#single-pager a.cycle-pager-active img {
  opacity: 0.4;
}

#single-left,
#single-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1000;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
  padding: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#single-left {
  left: 0;
}

#single-right {
  right: 0;
}

.filter {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #FFF;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  padding: 10px 30px;
}

.filter li {
  list-style-type: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  padding: 5px;
}

a[data-hidden="true"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lightgallery/latest/css/lightgallery.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="single-gallery" id="single-gallery">
  <div class="single-gallery-carousel">
    <div class="slideshow-area">
      <ul class="filter">
        <li id="sports">Sports</li>
        <li id="naturel">Naturel</li>
        <li id="animals">Animals</li>
        <li id="show-all">All</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="mySlideShow">
      <a data-exthumbimage="http://cdn.anitur.com.tr/resimler/normal/2014-02/tur_kuba_CP62I36hoYGMpFFRiN78.jpg" data-id="naturel" data-hidden="false" data-src="http://cdn.anitur.com.tr/resimler/normal/2014-02/tur_kuba_CP62I36hoYGMpFFRiN78.jpg">
        <img class="lazyload" data-src="https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/static/img/12.jpg" data-poster="https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/static/img/12.jpg">
      </a>

      <a class="video" data-hidden="false" data-id="naturel" data-src="http://nerdist.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/The-Evolution-of-Pixar.jpg" href="https://vimeo.com/1084537">
        <img class="lazyload" data-src="http://nerdist.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/The-Evolution-of-Pixar.jpg">
      </a>

      <a data-exthumbimage="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/images/h494/2017-03/otel_aurum-didyma-spa-beach-resort_sReNOBXcinbZI7lNGf3x.jpg" data-hidden="false" data-id="naturel" data-src="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/images/h494/2017-03/otel_aurum-didyma-spa-beach-resort_sReNOBXcinbZI7lNGf3x.jpg">
        <img  data-exthumbimage="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/images/h494/2017-03/otel_aurum-didyma-spa-beach-resort_sReNOBXcinbZI7lNGf3x.jpg" class="lazyload" data-src="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/images/h494/2017-03/otel_aurum-didyma-spa-beach-resort_sReNOBXcinbZI7lNGf3x.jpg" data-poster="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/images/h494/2017-03/otel_aurum-didyma-spa-beach-resort_sReNOBXcinbZI7lNGf3x.jpg">
      </a>

      <a data-exthumbimage="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/tulips-lightbox.jpg" data-hidden="false" data-id="animals" data-src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/tulips-lightbox.jpg">
        <img class="lazyload" data-src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/tulips-lightbox.jpg" data-poster="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/tulips-lightbox.jpg">
      </a>

      <a data-exthumbimage="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/golden-wheat-field-lightbox.jpg" data-hidden="false" data-id="sports" data-src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/golden-wheat-field-lightbox.jpg">
        <img class="lazyload" data-src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/golden-wheat-field-lightbox.jpg" data-poster="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/golden-wheat-field-lightbox.jpg"></a>

      <a data-exthumbimage="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/night-in-the-city-lightbox.jpg" data-hidden="false" data-id="sports" data-src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/night-in-the-city-lightbox.jpg">
        <img class="lazyload" data-src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/night-in-the-city-lightbox.jpg" data-poster="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/night-in-the-city-lightbox.jpg"></a>

      <a data-exthumbimage="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/night-in-the-city-lightbox.jpg" data-hidden="false" data-id="sports" data-src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/night-in-the-city-lightbox.jpg">
        <img class="lazyload" data-src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/night-in-the-city-lightbox.jpg" data-poster="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/dandelion-lightbox.jpg"></a>

      <a data-exthumbimage="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/dandelion-lightbox.jpg" data-hidden="false" data-id="animals" data-src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/dandelion-lightbox.jpg">
        <img class="lazyload" data-src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/dandelion-lightbox.jpg" data-poster="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/dandelion-lightbox.jpg">
      </a>

      <a data-exthumbimage="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/daffodil-flowers-lightbox.jpg" data-hidden="false" data-id="sports" data-src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/daffodil-flowers-lightbox.jpg">
        <img class="lazyload" data-src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/daffodil-flowers-lightbox.jpg" data-poster="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/daffodil-flowers-lightbox.jpg">
      </a>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="center external" id="single-pager">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="single-next-prev">
  <span class="ani-icon-chevron-pointing-to-the-left ani-cycle-control" id="single-left"></span> <span class="ani-icon-right-chevron ani-cycle-control" id="single-right"></span>
</div>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.cycle2/2.1.6/jquery.cycle2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/1.3.9/js/lightgallery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lazysizes/3.0.0/lazysizes.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you using angular?

Comment: no I'm only using jquery

Comment: Why do you use **{{ curly brackets }}** then?

Comment: Sorry i haven't used `cycle2` before, that's why i'm asking. The syntax looked just like `angular` and i thought that might be a `dependency` issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be a JQuery Issue, i am not so sure of it :) but after destroying the cycle, options are not set correctly. To overcome this issue tweaking @Chris Happy's answer a little bit:

**Define the options inside a variable, so that you may have chance to manupulate it.** Like so :

`options = {
      next: "#single-right",
      log: false,
      fx: "fade",
      caption: ".cycle-caption",
      captionTemplate: "{{title}}",
      pauseOnHover: true,
      pager: "#single-pager",
      pagerTemplate: "<a href='#'><img class=lazyload data-src={{exthumbimage}} width=60 height=60></a>",
      prev: "#single-left",
      slides: "a[data-hidden='false']"
}`

And later on, right after you destroy the cycle, just change the **options object** by adding a line before re-initiating the cycle function:

```
options['pagerTemplate'] = "<a href='#'><img src='{{children.0.src}}' class='lazyload' width=60 height=60></a>"
```

Below is the working code. Hope this works.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
options = {
      next: "#single-right",
      log: false,
      fx: "fade",
      caption: ".cycle-caption",
      captionTemplate: "{{title}}",
      pauseOnHover: true,
      pager: "#single-pager",
      pagerTemplate: "<a href='#'><img class=lazyload data-src={{exthumbimage}} width=60 height=60></a>",
      prev: "#single-left",
      slides: "a[data-hidden='false']"
}
  function generateSlider(opt) {
    $(".mySlideShow").cycle(opt);
  }

  generateSlider(options);

  $(".filter li").on("click", function() {
    var activeId = $(this).attr("id");
    if (activeId == "show-all") {
      $("a").attr("data-hidden", "false");
    } else {
      $("a").attr("data-hidden", "true");
      $("a[data-id = '" + activeId + "']").attr("data-hidden", "false");
    }
    $(".mySlideShow").cycle("destroy");
    options['pagerTemplate'] = "<a href='#'><img src='{{children.0.src}}' class='lazyload' width=60 height=60></a>"
    generateSlider(options);
  });

  $(" .mySlideShow").lightGallery({
    exThumbImage: "data-exthumbimage",
    download: false,
    thumbnail: true,
    loadYoutubeThumbnail: true,
    youtubeThumbSize: "default",
    loadVimeoThumbnail: true,
    vimeoThumbSize: "thumbnail_medium"
  });
});
```

```css
.single-gallery {
  width: 800px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.cycle-slideshow img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 494px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

#single-pager a img {
  width: 49.3px !important;
  height: 49.3px !important;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

#single-pager a.cycle-pager-active img {
  opacity: 0.4;
}

#single-left,
#single-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1000;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
  padding: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#single-left {
  left: 0;
}

#single-right {
  right: 0;
}

.filter {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #FFF;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  padding: 10px 30px;
}

.filter li {
  list-style-type: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  padding: 5px;
}

a[data-hidden="true"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lightgallery/latest/css/lightgallery.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="single-gallery" id="single-gallery">
  <div class="single-gallery-carousel">
   <div class="slideshow-area">
        <ul class="filter">
              <li id="sports">Sports</li>
              <li id="naturel">Naturel</li>
              <li id="animals">Animals</li>
              <li id="show-all">All</li>
            </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="mySlideShow">
      <a data-exthumbimage="http://cdn.anitur.com.tr/resimler/normal/2014-02/tur_kuba_CP62I36hoYGMpFFRiN78.jpg" data-id="naturel"  data-hidden="false" data-src="http://cdn.anitur.com.tr/resimler/normal/2014-02/tur_kuba_CP62I36hoYGMpFFRiN78.jpg">
             <img class="lazyload" data-src="https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/static/img/12.jpg" data-poster="https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/static/img/12.jpg">
          </a> 
          
          <a data-exthumbimage="http://nerdist.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/The-Evolution-of-Pixar.jpg" href="https://vimeo.com/1084537" class="video" data-hidden="false" data-id="naturel" data-src="http://nerdist.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/The-Evolution-of-Pixar.jpg" href="https://vimeo.com/1084537">
            <img class="lazyload" data-src="http://nerdist.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/The-Evolution-of-Pixar.jpg">
          </a> 
          
          <a data-exthumbimage="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/images/h494/2017-03/otel_aurum-didyma-spa-beach-resort_sReNOBXcinbZI7lNGf3x.jpg" data-hidden="false" data-id="naturel" data-src="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/images/h494/2017-03/otel_aurum-didyma-spa-beach-resort_sReNOBXcinbZI7lNGf3x.jpg">
            <img class="lazyload" data-src="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/images/h494/2017-03/otel_aurum-didyma-spa-beach-resort_sReNOBXcinbZI7lNGf3x.jpg" data-poster="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/images/h494/2017-03/otel_aurum-didyma-spa-beach-resort_sReNOBXcinbZI7lNGf3x.jpg">
          </a> 
          
          <a data-exthumbimage="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/tulips-lightbox.jpg" data-hidden="false" data-id="animals" data-src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/tulips-lightbox.jpg">
            <img class="lazyload" data-src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/tulips-lightbox.jpg" data-poster="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/tulips-lightbox.jpg">
            </a> 
          
          <a data-exthumbimage="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/golden-wheat-field-lightbox.jpg" data-hidden="false" data-id="sports" data-src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/golden-wheat-field-lightbox.jpg">
            <img class="lazyload" data-src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/golden-wheat-field-lightbox.jpg" data-poster="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/golden-wheat-field-lightbox.jpg" ></a> 
          
          <a data-exthumbimage="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/night-in-the-city-lightbox.jpg" data-hidden="false" data-id="sports" data-src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/night-in-the-city-lightbox.jpg">
            <img class="lazyload" data-src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/night-in-the-city-lightbox.jpg" data-poster="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/night-in-the-city-lightbox.jpg" ></a> 
          
          <a data-exthumbimage="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/night-in-the-city-lightbox.jpg" data-hidden="false" data-id="sports" data-src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/night-in-the-city-lightbox.jpg">
            <img class="lazyload" data-src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/night-in-the-city-lightbox.jpg" data-poster="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/dandelion-lightbox.jpg" ></a> 
          
          <a data-exthumbimage="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/dandelion-lightbox.jpg" data-hidden="false" data-id="animals" data-src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/dandelion-lightbox.jpg">
            <img class="lazyload" data-src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/dandelion-lightbox.jpg" data-poster="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/dandelion-lightbox.jpg" >
          </a> 
          
          <a data-exthumbimage="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/daffodil-flowers-lightbox.jpg" data-hidden="false" data-id="sports" data-src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/daffodil-flowers-lightbox.jpg">
            <img class="lazyload" data-src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/daffodil-flowers-lightbox.jpg"  data-poster="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/daffodil-flowers-lightbox.jpg" >
          </a>
          
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="center external" id="single-pager">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="single-next-prev">
   <span class="ani-icon-chevron-pointing-to-the-left ani-cycle-control" id="single-left"></span> <span class="ani-icon-right-chevron ani-cycle-control" id="single-right"></span>
  </div>
 </div>
  
  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.cycle2/2.1.6/jquery.cycle2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/1.3.9/js/lightgallery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lazysizes/3.0.0/lazysizes.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: so it works very well and would you mind if I ask a question again ? after select a category lightgallery is not working because of this  should we regenerate lightgallery again?

Comment: Actually it is working in the example above, when you run the snippet you'll see. And it is working on my laptop also. There might be a conflict with the rest f your code, i don't know. But i can't simulate your problem here, as it does work. `incelemek lazım`

Comment: actually yes it works very well with light slider but when we changed lightgallery path with this: `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lightgallery@1.3.5,lg-fullscreen@1.0.1,lg-hash@1.0.1,lg-pager@1.0.1,lg-share@1.0.1,lg-thumbnail@1.0.1,lg-video@1.0.1,lg-autoplay@1.0.1"></script>` than lightgallery is not working because this path include also thumbnail.js,video.js - demo:http://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/WjOEeE  `tesekkurler kardesim cok yardimci oldun `

Answer (score 1):

Okay, do the following:

- Remove the quotes from the pagerTemplate
- Use `{{exthumbimage}}` for `data-src`. `{{parents.0.exthumbimage}}` would select the `a`'s parent with is the slider itself. For it's own attribute, you just have to use the name of that attribute.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function generateSlider() {
    $(".mySlideShow").cycle({
      next: "#single-right",
      log: false,
      fx: "fade",
      caption: ".cycle-caption",
      captionTemplate: "{{title}}",
      pauseOnHover: true,
      pager: "#single-pager",
      pagerTemplate: "<a href='#'><img class=lazyload data-src={{exthumbimage}} width=60 height=60></a>",
      prev: "#single-left",
      slides: "a[data-hidden='false']"
    });
  }

  generateSlider();

  $(".filter li").on("click", function() {
    var activeId = $(this).attr("id");
    if (activeId == "show-all") {
      $("a").attr("data-hidden", "false");
    } else {
      $("a").attr("data-hidden", "true");
      $("a[data-id = '" + activeId + "']").attr("data-hidden", "false");
    }
    $(".mySlideShow").cycle("destroy");
    generateSlider();
  });

  $(" .mySlideShow").lightGallery({
    exThumbImage: "data-exthumbimage",
    download: false,
    thumbnail: true,
    loadYoutubeThumbnail: true,
    youtubeThumbSize: "default",
    loadVimeoThumbnail: true,
    vimeoThumbSize: "thumbnail_medium"
  });
});
```

```css
.single-gallery {
  width: 800px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.cycle-slideshow img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 494px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

#single-pager a img {
  width: 49.3px !important;
  height: 49.3px !important;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

#single-pager a.cycle-pager-active img {
  opacity: 0.4;
}

#single-left,
#single-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1000;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
  padding: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#single-left {
  left: 0;
}

#single-right {
  right: 0;
}

.filter {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #FFF;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  padding: 10px 30px;
}

.filter li {
  list-style-type: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  padding: 5px;
}

a[data-hidden="true"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lightgallery/latest/css/lightgallery.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="single-gallery" id="single-gallery">
  <div class="single-gallery-carousel">
   <div class="slideshow-area">
        <ul class="filter">
              <li id="sports">Sports</li>
              <li id="naturel">Naturel</li>
              <li id="animals">Animals</li>
              <li id="show-all">All</li>
            </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="mySlideShow">
      <a data-exthumbimage="http://cdn.anitur.com.tr/resimler/normal/2014-02/tur_kuba_CP62I36hoYGMpFFRiN78.jpg" data-id="naturel"  data-hidden="false" data-src="http://cdn.anitur.com.tr/resimler/normal/2014-02/tur_kuba_CP62I36hoYGMpFFRiN78.jpg">
             <img class="lazyload" data-src="https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/static/img/12.jpg" data-poster="https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/static/img/12.jpg">
          </a> 
          
          <a data-exthumbimage="http://nerdist.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/The-Evolution-of-Pixar.jpg" href="https://vimeo.com/1084537" class="video" data-hidden="false" data-id="naturel" data-src="http://nerdist.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/The-Evolution-of-Pixar.jpg" href="https://vimeo.com/1084537">
            <img class="lazyload" data-src="http://nerdist.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/The-Evolution-of-Pixar.jpg">
          </a> 
          
          <a data-exthumbimage="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/images/h494/2017-03/otel_aurum-didyma-spa-beach-resort_sReNOBXcinbZI7lNGf3x.jpg" data-hidden="false" data-id="naturel" data-src="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/images/h494/2017-03/otel_aurum-didyma-spa-beach-resort_sReNOBXcinbZI7lNGf3x.jpg">
            <img class="lazyload" data-src="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/images/h494/2017-03/otel_aurum-didyma-spa-beach-resort_sReNOBXcinbZI7lNGf3x.jpg" data-poster="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/images/h494/2017-03/otel_aurum-didyma-spa-beach-resort_sReNOBXcinbZI7lNGf3x.jpg">
          </a> 
          
          <a data-exthumbimage="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/tulips-lightbox.jpg" data-hidden="false" data-id="animals" data-src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/tulips-lightbox.jpg">
            <img class="lazyload" data-src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/tulips-lightbox.jpg" data-poster="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/tulips-lightbox.jpg">
            </a> 
          
          <a data-exthumbimage="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/golden-wheat-field-lightbox.jpg" data-hidden="false" data-id="sports" data-src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/golden-wheat-field-lightbox.jpg">
            <img class="lazyload" data-src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/golden-wheat-field-lightbox.jpg" data-poster="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/golden-wheat-field-lightbox.jpg" ></a> 
          
          <a data-exthumbimage="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/night-in-the-city-lightbox.jpg" data-hidden="false" data-id="sports" data-src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/night-in-the-city-lightbox.jpg">
            <img class="lazyload" data-src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/night-in-the-city-lightbox.jpg" data-poster="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/night-in-the-city-lightbox.jpg" ></a> 
          
          <a data-exthumbimage="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/night-in-the-city-lightbox.jpg" data-hidden="false" data-id="sports" data-src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/night-in-the-city-lightbox.jpg">
            <img class="lazyload" data-src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/night-in-the-city-lightbox.jpg" data-poster="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/dandelion-lightbox.jpg" ></a> 
          
          <a data-exthumbimage="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/dandelion-lightbox.jpg" data-hidden="false" data-id="animals" data-src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/dandelion-lightbox.jpg">
            <img class="lazyload" data-src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/dandelion-lightbox.jpg" data-poster="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/dandelion-lightbox.jpg" >
          </a> 
          
          <a data-exthumbimage="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/daffodil-flowers-lightbox.jpg" data-hidden="false" data-id="sports" data-src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/daffodil-flowers-lightbox.jpg">
            <img class="lazyload" data-src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/daffodil-flowers-lightbox.jpg"  data-poster="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/daffodil-flowers-lightbox.jpg" >
          </a>
          
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="center external" id="single-pager">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="single-next-prev">
   <span class="ani-icon-chevron-pointing-to-the-left ani-cycle-control" id="single-left"></span> <span class="ani-icon-right-chevron ani-cycle-control" id="single-right"></span>
  </div>
 </div>
  
  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.cycle2/2.1.6/jquery.cycle2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/1.3.9/js/lightgallery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lazysizes/3.0.0/lazysizes.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I know this way but after click any category than thumbnails doesn't appear anymore :)